# Basis of a subspace defined by a linear equation.

Tags: vector-spaces

Find a basis of the subspace of $${\mathbb R}^3$$ defined by the equation $$-9 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 2 x_3 = 0$$

I'm looking on how to approach this problem since my instructor only showed us how to prove if they are linearly independent or not and I can't find any sources on line.. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Essentially the equation you are describing, is a plane in R3. How many (independent) vectors do you need to arrive at any point on this plane, starting from Origin?

Comment: 3. One in x, one in y, one in z?

Comment: No, a vector equation to describe your plane only needs two (!!) independent vectors. Each vector does have three entries though.

Comment: But isn't plane R3 a 3 dimensional space?

Comment: To describe the entire R3 you indeed need 3 vectors. But your plane is a two dimensional space in R3. So you would need only two vectors

Comment: So then is R4 needing 4 vectors but also in a two dimensional space?

Comment: To span R4 itself you would need 4 vectors. To span a subset in R4, it depends on what the subset is... It is however important to realize that in your given equation, the first two variables are "free" but once chosen, then the third variable is now known. Therefore you need two vectors to span that subspace

Comment: See answer of Seoanes. That is pretty much what I am implying. Make sure you would never choose the zero vector as that creates a dependent set.

Answer (score 2):

You were given one equation and three variables. It would mean that you get two free parameters (your final space will have dimension=2). You can choose for example $x_1=1,x_2=0$ getting $x_3=9/2$ and $x_1=0,x_2=1$ obtaining $x_3=-3/2$ (this choice is generally free). Then, two independent vectors of the subspace are:
$$\left(1,0,\frac{9}{2}\right)\\
\left(0,1,\frac{-3}{2}\right)$$
Finally, you can take care about aesthetics and eliminate the fractions multiplying by two
$$\left(2,0,9\right)\\
\left(0,2,-3\right)$$
Any other vector you can find in your subspace will be linearly dependent on these two the vectors

Comment: It is better two provide vectors without fractions...

Comment: Suggestion included :)

Answer (score 1):

The space is $\mathbb R^3$. You are given one equation, which will define a two-dimensional plane. Any two independent vectors in the plane are a basis. So find two anysolutions to the equation, that are not linear dependent.

Comment: So would $$x1 = 2, x2=2, getting x3 =6$$ $$x1=0 x2=8 getting x=-12$$ work?

Comment: @DavidScidmore do they both solve the equation and are they linearly independent?

Comment: They both solve the equation and appear to be linearly independent since the components have to be multiplied by different numbers from each other.